# How can I send text to a console window like cmd from C++?

Tags: c++, console, send, sendmessage, findwindow

I have cmd.exe already open, and now I need to send commands to it from my running C++ program, how can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: yeah, things like 

 HWND GameWindow = FindWindow(0, L"Administrator: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe");
 PostMessage(GameWindow, WM_KEYDOWN, 'G', 0);

Comment: This question looks like it might be closed fairly soon. @Haalef, take a look at [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and see if you can edit your question to improve it. You'll be more likely to get help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Steve, I just edited the question so it may be easier to understand now.

Comment: @Haalef That's a much better example. Maybe if you can edit your question and construct a very minimal example of how that plays out you'll get a more specific answer. Right now it's hard to tell what you mean by "Commands", as in, do you mean to just execute shell commands in a different window? Or simply emulate keystrokes?

Comment: @tadman, keystrokes would be perfect, send keystrokes to cmd.exe. If I can do that then I assume I can also send those keystrokes in the same way to a running telnet client console.

Comment: Maybe if you described your final goals in more specific detail there might be a better way to solve this problem. Anything that involves `telnet.exe` is usually a bad plan.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot be more specific than that, but thanks anyway for trying to help.